# Javax Validation API doesnt work with @NotEmpty and @Size

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, spring-annotations

Given the below controller method which takes in request body with path variable, I have annotated the request body object with javax annotations.

Since my spring boot version is later than 2.3.0 I've added `spring-boot-starter-validation` dependency to the `pom.xml` file manually.

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
public class QueryController {


   @PostMapping(value = "/customer/{id}", produces = {APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
   public Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>> submitCustomerQuery(@RequestBody @Valid final QueryRequest request,
                                                        @PathVariable("id") @NotBlank final String id) {
     // calling the service 
   }

}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class QueryRequest {
   @NotEmpty(message = "Query cant be empty")
   @Size(max = 160, message = "Query cant exceed 160 characters")
   private String instruction;
}
```

As I'm using one of the parent dependencies into the project I didn't use the javax.validation dependency explicitly, since `validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar` file is already in the class path.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>uk.co.abc.common_infrastructure.java</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-parent-pom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.9</version>
</parent>

<spring.boot.version>2.5.2</spring.boot.version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Still I couldn't get the validations to work in case when request exceeds the validation for 160 characters. What am I missing? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What I missing was, I had not reloaded the maven dependencies properly which made `hibernate-validator-6.2.0.Final.jar` being not in the classpath as an external library (which gets sorted by `spring-boot-starter-validation`)